# How do I set PYTHONPATH / Installing Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pythonpath

I am trying to run a small program from the command line under Linux. The program runs correctly when I use IDLE but I cant run it from the command line. I ran this little program to tell me my path:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Under IDLE I have the following entry:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

These entries are not there when I run under the command line. The package that I need to import (selenium) is in dist-packages. I get the following error when trying to import selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
...
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

I have tried pip install selenium, pip uninstall selenium, doesnt fix the problem. When I try python setup.py install (on the selenium install file) I get:

```
error: invalid command 'easy_install'
```

How can I solve this problem - do I have to add:  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages 
to my path, and if so how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do one of the following:

1.Add the path to sys.path

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
```

2.Add to `PYTHONPATH` from commandline

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"
```